# get average from one column structured query language

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions, having

App usage data are kept in the following table:

```
TABLE sessions
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  userId INTEGER NOT NULL,
  duration DECIMAL NOT NULL
```

Write a query that selects userId and average session duration for each user who has more than one session.

Can you guys help write this simple query? I'm literally just starting out.

Comment: you can use `GROUP BY`,  `AVG` and `HAVING` keywords

Answer (score 2):

As @Serkan Arslan suggested, Use the following, literally :

```
select userId "User Id", avg(duration) "Avg. Duration"
  from sessions
 group by userId 
 having count(1)>1;
```